# Export to Excel: export text area contents in single cell "with line break within the cell /Alt + Enter" using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, export-to-excel

I am trying to export a string entered through textarea into excel using javascript as following, but so far the method I tried not working for me.

Desired Results:

[image]

I tried string in following format

var try1="line 1\nline 2\n\nline 4"

var try2="line 1\r\nline 2\r\n\nline 4"

var try3="line 1/r/nline 2/r/n/nline 4"

var try4="line 1" + "\t" + "\"" + "line 1" + "\n" + "line 2" + "\"\t" + "other content";

any suggestion/guidance how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = line + "\t" + "\"" + line + "\n" + newline + "\"\t" + line;
```

An old answer from a webmaster forum. Check if any of those work for you

Comment: as mentioned in the question I already tried it
var try4="line 1" + "\t" + "\"" + "line 1" + "\n" + "line 2" + "\"\t" + "other content"